# Security Advisory: Cisco RV320 or RV325 Routers are Hackable World Wide

Tags: cisco, router, firmware

> If the connectivity and security of your organization rely on Cisco
>   RV320 or RV325 Dual Gigabit WAN VPN routers, then you need to
>   immediately install the latest firmware update released by the vendor
>   last week.
>
> Cyber attackers have actively been exploiting two newly patched
>   high-severity router vulnerabilities in the wild after a security
>   researcher released their [proof-of-concept](https://github.com/0x27/CiscoRV320Dump) exploit code on the
>   Internet last weekend.
>
> The vulnerabilities in question are a command injection flaw (assigned
>   CVE-2019-1652) and an information disclosure flaw (assigned
>   CVE-2019-1653), a combination of which could allow a remote attacker
>   to take full control of an affected Cisco router.
>
> The first issue exists in RV320 and RV325 dual gigabit WAN VPN routers
>   running firmware versions 1.4.2.15 through 1.4.2.19, and the second
>   affects firmware versions 1.4.2.15 and 1.4.2.17, according to the
>   [Cisco’s advisory](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20190123-rv-inject).
>
> Both the vulnerabilities, discovered and responsibly reported to the
>   company by German security firm RedTeam Pentesting, actually resides
>   in the web-based management interface used for the routers and are
>   remotely exploitable.
>
> - CVE-2019-1652—The flaw allows an authenticated, remote attacker with    administrative privileges on an affected device to execute
>     arbitrary    commands on the system.
> - CVE-2019-1653—This flaw doesn't require any authentication to reach    the router's web-based management portal, allowing attackers to
>     retrieve sensitive information including the router's configuration
>     file containing MD5 hashed credentials and diagnostic information.
>
> The PoC exploit code targeting Cisco RV320/RV325 routers published on
>   the Internet first exploits CVE-2019-1653 to retrieve the
>   configuration file from the router to obtain its hashed credentials
>   and then exploits CVE-2019-1652 to execute arbitrary commands and gain
>   complete control of the affected device.
>
> Researchers from cybersecurity firm [Bad Packets](https://badpackets.net/over-9000-cisco-rv320-rv325-routers-vulnerable-to-cve-2019-1653/) said they found
>   at least 9,657 Cisco routers (6,247 RV320 and 3,410 RV325) worldwide
>   that are vulnerable to the information disclosure vulnerability, most
>   of which located in the United States.
>
> The firm shared an [interactive map](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZocV8n4DOmcKJ_ugjjQ_gjIAmDHxT1JBhVxIAdABVyY/edit#gid=1297196434), showing all vulnerable
>   RV320/RV325 Cisco routers in 122 countries and on the network of 1,619
>   unique internet service providers.
>
> Bad Packets said its honeypots detected opportunistic scanning
>   activity for vulnerable routers from multiple hosts from Saturday,
>   suggesting the hackers are actively trying to exploit the flaws to
>   take full control of the vulnerable routers.

Source: **https://thehackernews.com/2019/01/hacking-cisco-routers.html**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The best way to protect yourself from becoming the target of one such
>   attack is to install the latest Cisco RV320 and RV325 [Firmware
>   release 1.4.2.20](https://software.cisco.com/download/home/284005929/type/282465789/release/1.4.2.20?catid=268437899) as soon as possible.
>
> Administrators who have not yet applied the firmware update are highly
>   recommended to change their router's admin and WiFi credentials
>   considering themselves already compromised.